# PHP POST element from append javascript

Tags: javascript, php, post, append

im trying to post submit the form with element in append.

How can i POST submit to php the append elements in javascript?

here's the table where i use to append.

```
<tbody>

    <tr onload="calculate()">

        <?php

        foreach ($conn->query("SELECT * FROM panapricelist") as $info){

            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='promotitle' name='check' value='".$info['ProductId']."' ></td>";
            echo "<td><textarea rows='4' cols='7' maxlength='60'  name='pcode' class='pcode' id='ProductCode' disabled>".$info['ProductCode']."</textarea></td>";
            echo "<td><br><textarea rows='5' cols='40' maxlength='50' name='puse' class='productuse' id='productuse' disabled>".$info['ProductUse']." </textarea></td>";
            echo "<td><br><textarea rows='4' cols='50' maxlength='50' name='pdesc' class='description' id='productDesc' disabled>".$info['ProductDesc']."</textarea></td>";
            echo "<td id='msrp'><textarea rows='4' cols='10' maxlength='50' name='Msrp' class='msrp' id='productMsrp' disabled>".$info['Msrp']."</textarea></td>";
            echo "<td style='width: 10%;'><textarea rows='4' cols='10' name='Dealerphp' maxlength='50' class='cost' id='cost' disabled>".$info['DealerPhp']."</textarea></td></tr>";
        }
        ?>

</tbody>
```

here's the append js

```
var getRow = $(this).parents('tr'); //variable for the entire row
var value =  (getRow.find('td:eq(1)').html()); // Product Code
var value1 = (getRow.find('td:eq(2)').html()); // for Suggested Product Use
var value2 = (getRow.find('td:eq(3)').html()); // for product Description
var value3 = (getRow.find('td:eq(4)').html()); // for MSRP PHP
var value4 = (getRow.find('td:eq(5)').html()); // for Dealer PHP
var value5 = (getRow.find('td:eq(0)').html()); // for Dealer PHP
$('#item-row').append('<tr><td class="item-name"><textarea value="'+ value +'</textarea></td><td class="item-name"><textarea class="check" name="check[]" value= "' + value1 + ' </textarea> </td><td class="item-name"><textarea value= "' + value2 +' </textarea></td><td class="item-name"><textarea value= "' + value3 + ' </textarea>  </td><td><textarea name="Msrp" value="' + value4 + '</textarea></td><td class="item-name"><textarea class="qty" id="qty" name="qty[]"> </textarea></td><td class="item-name"><textarea id="price" class="price" name="price[]" disabled></textarea></td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the table in a form

```html
<form method="POST" action='action.php' id="my_form">
<table>
<tbody>

    <tr onload="calculate()">

        <?php
          
        foreach ($conn->query("SELECT * FROM panapricelist") as $info){

            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='promotitle' name='check' value='".$info['ProductId']."' ></td>";
            echo "<td><textarea rows='4' cols='7' maxlength='60'  name='pcode[]' class='pcode' id='ProductCode' disabled>".$info['ProductCode']."</textarea></td>";
            echo "<td><br><textarea rows='5' cols='40' maxlength='50' name='puse[]' class='productuse' id='productuse' disabled>".$info['ProductUse']." </textarea></td>";
            echo "<td><br><textarea rows='4' cols='50' maxlength='50' name='pdesc[]' class='description' id='productDesc' disabled>".$info['ProductDesc']."</textarea></td>";
            echo "<td id='msrp'><textarea rows='4' cols='10' maxlength='50' name='Msrp[]' class='msrp' id='productMsrp' disabled>".$info['Msrp']."</textarea></td>";
            echo "<td style='width: 10%;'><textarea rows='4' cols='10' name='Dealerphp[]' maxlength='50' class='cost' id='cost' disabled>".$info['DealerPhp']."</textarea></td></tr>";
        }
        ?>

</tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) for interact from javascript to PHP.
You may see this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Tegos/azpk0jed/).

```
$('#send').click(() => {
  let data = $('.form :input').serialize();
  console.log(data);
  $('#response').html(data);
  $.ajax({
    url: '/',
    type: 'post',
    data,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
      $('#response').html(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```